# Problems with starting on android device. Error with react-native-navigation

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation-v2

After run npm run android --stacktrace, I have an error:

> Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57_5DebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

error: NoOpPromise is not abstract and does not override abstract method reject(String,String,Throwable,WritableMap) in Promise
public class NoOpPromise implements Promise {

react-native": "^0.58.1",

"react-native-navigation": "^2.8.0",

Comment: have you tried to install and compile again, https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4639 according to this issue they had a problem with android and ios but android is somehow fixed.

Comment: You can still downgrade to other versions to avoid this problem

Comment: I think the latest version is not stable as we thought it is, so probably the best choice is to downgrade and wait for the latest version to be stable.

Comment: Did work for me. Also didn't need to downgrade. I'm running on RN 0.58

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to override the methods that the `NoOpPromise.java` class is not overriding. This issue is with react-native 0.58.1. Either you can degrade the version or you can make the changes in the NoOpPromise file.Please checkout my answer on [github](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4646#issuecomment-458199026).

Enjoy Coding!!!!!!